# threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c3a1f8)

Tags: android

Приложение вылетает при отладке через usb

```
package com.ftg;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import com.parser.JSONParser;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class EditRouteActivity extends Activity {

    EditText editRoute_name;
    EditText editRoute_desc;
    Button btnSave;
    Button btnDelete;

    String route_id;

    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

    // url для получения одного маршрута
    private static final String url_route_detials = "http://172.16.0.100/route_get_details.php";

    // url для обновления маршрута
    private static final String url_update_route = "http://172.16.0.100/route_update.php";

    // url для удаления маршрута
    private static final String url_delete_route = "http://172.16.0.100/route_delete.php";

    // JSON параметры
    private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
    private static final String TAG_ROUTE = "route";
    private static final String TAG_ROUTE_ID = "route_id";
    private static final String TAG_ROUTE_NAME = "route_name";
    private static final String TAG_ROUTE_DESCRIPTION = "route_description";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edit_route);

        btnSave = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSave);
        btnDelete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);

        // показываем форму про детальную информацию о маршруте
        Intent i = getIntent();

        // получаем id маршрута (route_id) с формы
        route_id = i.getStringExtra(TAG_ROUTE_ID);

        // Получение полной информации о маршруте в фоновом потоке
        new GetRouteDetails().execute();

        // обрабочик на кнопку сохранение маршрута
        btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // запускаем выполнение задачи на обновление маршрута
                new SaveRouteDetails().execute();
            }
        });

        // обработчик на кнопку удаление маршрута
        btnDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                // удалем маршрут в фоновом потоке
                new DeleteRoute().execute();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * Фоновая асинхронная задача для получения полной информации о маршруте
     **/
    class GetRouteDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>{

        /**
         * Перед началом показать в фоновом потоке прогресс диалог
         **/
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditRouteActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Loading route details. Please wait...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Получение детальной информации о продукте в фоновом режиме
         **/
        protected String doInBackground(String[] params) {

            // обновляем UI форму
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // проверяем статус success тега
                    int success;
                    try {
                        // Список параметров
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("route_id", route_id));

                        // получаем продукт по HTTP запросу
                        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_route_detials, "GET", params);

                        Log.d("Single Route Details", json.toString());

                        success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                        if (success == 1) {
                            // Успешно получена детальная информация о маршруте
                            JSONArray routeObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_ROUTE);

                            // получаем первый обьект с JSON Array
                            JSONObject route = routeObj.getJSONObject(0);

                            // продукт с route_id найден
                            // Edit Text
                            editRoute_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputRouteEdit_name);
                            editRoute_desc = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputRouteEdit_desc);

                            // покаываем данные о продукте в EditText
                            editRoute_name.setText(route.getString(TAG_ROUTE_NAME));
                            editRoute_desc.setText(route.getString(TAG_ROUTE_DESCRIPTION));

                        }else{
                            // продукт с route_id не найден
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * После завершения фоновой задачи закрываем диалог прогресс
         **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // закрываем диалог прогресс
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    /**
     * В фоновом режиме выполняем асинхроную задачу на сохранение маршрута
     **/
    class SaveRouteDetails extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * Перед началом показываем в фоновом потоке прогрксс диалог
         **/
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditRouteActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Saving route ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Сохраняем маршрут
         **/
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            // получаем обновленные данные с EditTexts
            String route_name = editRoute_name.getText().toString();
            String route_description = editRoute_desc.getText().toString();

            // формируем параметры
            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_ROUTE_ID, route_id));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_ROUTE_NAME, route_name));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair(TAG_ROUTE_DESCRIPTION, route_description));

            // отправляем измененные данные через http запрос
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_update_route, "POST", params);

            // проверяем json success тег
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // продукт удачно обнавлён
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    // отправляем результирующий код 100 чтобы сообщить об обновлении продукта
                    setResult(100, i);
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // продукт не обновлен
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * После окончания закрываем прогресс диалог
         **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            // закрываем прогресс диалог
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Фоновая асинхронная задача на удаление продукта
     **/
    class DeleteRoute extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        /**
         * На начале показываем прогресс диалог
         **/
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(EditRouteActivity.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("УДАЛЕМ МАРШРУТ...");
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        /**
         * Удаление продукта
         **/
        protected String doInBackground(String... args) {

            int success;
            try {
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("route_id", route_id));

                // получение продукта используя HTTP запрос
                JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_delete_route, "POST", params);

                Log.d("Delete Product", json.toString());

                success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                if (success == 1) {
                    // Продукт удачно удален
                    Intent i = getIntent();
                    // отправляем результирующий код 100 для уведомления об удалении продукта
                    setResult(100, i);
                    finish();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        /**
         * После оконачния скрываем прогресс диалог
         **/
        protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

Вот log

> dalvikvm(32161): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c3a1f8)
>       06-10 02:20:49.711: E/AndroidRuntime(32161): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       06-10 02:20:49.711: E/AndroidRuntime(32161): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
>       06-10 02:20:49.711: E/AndroidRuntime(32161):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1105)
>       06-10 02:20:49.711: E/AndroidRuntime(32161):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
>       06-10 02:20:49.711: E/AndroidRuntime(32161):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
>       06-10 02:20:49.711: E/AndroidRuntime(32161):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
>       06-10 02:20:49.711: E/AndroidRuntime(32161):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
>       06-10 02:20:49.711: E/AndroidRuntime(32161):    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
>       06-10 02:20:49.711: E/AndroidRuntime(32161):    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:848)
>       06-10 02:20:49.711: E/AndroidRuntime(32161):    at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
>       06-10 02:20:49.711: E/AndroidRuntime(32161):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
>       06-10 02:20:49.711: E/AndroidRuntime(32161):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
>       06-10 02:20:49.711: E/AndroidRuntime(32161):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
>       06-10 02:20:49.711: E/AndroidRuntime(32161):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
>       06-10 02:20:49.711: E/AndroidRuntime(32161):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
>       06-10 02:20:49.711: E/AndroidRuntime(32161):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
>       06-10 02:20:49.711: E/AndroidRuntime(32161):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
>       06-10 02:20:49.711: E/AndroidRuntime(32161):    at com.parser.JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(JSONParser.java:54)
>       06-10 02:20:49.711: E/AndroidRuntime(32161):    at com.ftg.EditRouteActivity$GetRouteDetails$1.run(EditRouteActivity.java:125)
>       06-10 02:20:49.711: E/AndroidRuntime(32161):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
>       06-10 02:20:49.711: E/AndroidRuntime(32161):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>       06-10 02:20:49.711: E/AndroidRuntime(32161):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>       06-10 02:20:49.711: E/AndroidRuntime(32161):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
>       06-10 02:20:49.711: E/AndroidRuntime(32161):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       06-10 02:20:49.711: E/AndroidRuntime(32161):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
>       06-10 02:20:49.711: E/AndroidRuntime(32161):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:787)
>       06-10 02:20:49.711: E/AndroidRuntime(32161):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:554)
>       06-10 02:20:49.711: E/AndroidRuntime(32161):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас проблема в том, что на Андроиде с версии API>14 нельзя залезать в сеть в основном потоке. Вы же, вызывая **doInBackGround**, сразу же, в нём же, вызываете **runOnUiThread**, т.е. выполняете работу с сетью в основном потоке, о чём и говорит вам ваша ошибка - **NetworkOnMainThreadException**.

Вам нужно запомнить, что работу с элементами интерфейса надо проводить в основном потоке, к коему вы имеете доступ из **onPostExecute**. Т.е. в **doInBackGround** вы получаете данные из сети, передаёте их в **onPostExecute** и уже там работаете с кнопками на экране.

Comment: Спасибо, я перенёс в OnPostExecute                                   editRoute_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputRouteEdit_name); editRoute_desc =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.inputRouteEdit_desc);                 editRoute_name.setText(route.getString(TAG_ROUTE_NAME));                         editRoute_desc.setText(route.getString(TAG_ROUTE_DESCRIPTION);

Comment: Но я не понимаю пока что дожно возврашать doInBackGround

Comment: В doInBackGround вы должны возвращать полученные данные в нужном вам формате. Они появятся в виде аргумента метода в onPostExecute.